# why axis-1.4.jar is dependent upon wsdl4j-1.5.1 jar file in maven

Tags: maven-3

Container is already having wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar. I have observed that when I have written only
axis1.4 dependency code in my pom.xml, it automatically downloading axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar file which is also
creating problem to my existing application. could you please let me know,
why axis jar is internally downloading wsdl file and how to remove this
internal dependency

Comment: Why do you want to remove that dependency?

Comment: because it is causing issue when another application is trying to make the soap request to my app. and it is throwing invocation target exception.. when i remove jar manually it fixes the problem. Can you please help me to remove this from internal dependency

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html. read the last section, maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Like we declare needed artifacts as maven dependencies in pom for our java project, artifacts(declared as dependencies) are also projects and need other artifacts(dependencies).

According to [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/axis/axis-wsdl4j/usages) url, artifact-axis-1.4.jar is using artifact-axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.

That is why when you are trying to download the axis-1.4.jar, maven is automatically downloading its corresponding dependency - axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.

If your container is providing wsdl jar then you can tell maven to not to download axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar, by using the exclude tag in your pom file, like below -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

- Above declaration should solve your jar clashing problem.

  You can refer to [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) url suggested by Timo, to get the detailed explanation of exclude tag. *

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16135790)

Comment: @AbdullahKhan: I have updated my answer with explanation of - why maven is downloading the dependency - axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1 automatically and how we can avoid that problem using exclude tag. Kindly review and approve so that we can delete the reviewing comments from here.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16135790)

Comment: @JigneshAnsodariya : I have updated my answer with code that will solve the problem. Please review and approve.